# Mapbox for angular5

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I trying to use [mapbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-mapbox) in my angular 5 project but facing some issues as shown below

[image]

Is there any documentation of mapbox for updated version of angular?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that library is "dead" - e.g. hasn't been maintained in a year.

Please check this out: [Link to mapbox gl in github](https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl). 
This could serve as a replacement - compatible with angular 5 / 6.

Hope this helps.

Kind regards Chris